# Shell with server admin control

Tags: ssh

We have a long-term dispute in our company. The webdevelopers sometimes need to execute a command on the server, but the server admins do not allow them to use SSH, because they do not want to risk, that a webdeveloper makes some damage. The only way is an e-mail with the command on a server admin. Both sides are not satisfied with this solution.

Is there some better solution? Some tool, where the webdevelopers could write the commands, the server admins could control/edit/execute them and all admins and developers could see the responses?

Answer (score 1):

An obvious answer would be for the web developers to configure a tiny standalone web server on its own port and restricted access with 1 form for each command to run. Only the admins would be allowed to update it, after collective scrutiny. Choose a suitable server implementation language for the admins, eg perl, python, or even bash.